# How use ENV variables in Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT command

Tags: docker, dockerfile, environment-variables

I'm brand new user of Docker...

I'm tring use Enviroments variables on my Dockerfile...

It's like that:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim-buster
ENV JAVA_APP my-app
EXPOSE 8080
COPY target/$JAVA_APP-*.jar /app/$JAVA_APP.jar
CMD java -jar /app/$JAVA_APP.jar
```

The result is that: the `COPY` command gets the value of `JAVA_APP` variable. But the `CMD` command doesn't.

Is there some another way to use ENV variables?

Comment: Why do you want an environment variable here?  What happens if I `docker run -e JAVA_APP=something-else your-image`?  (I'd normally consider the image's filesystem layout fixed, and just go ahead and hard-code paths and filenames.)

Answer (score 0):

If I make this super simple Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV JAVA_APP my-app
CMD echo $JAVA_APP
```

and build and run it with

```
docker build -t test .
docker run --rm test
docker run --rm -e JAVA_APP=Hello test
```

It prints 'my-app' and 'Hello'. So it does work. If it still doesn't work for you, can you expand your post with the command you use to run the container?